# How to split a string with a Regex when the pattern "prefix" is variable

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have the following string:

> `Giants 2 9 : 10 L.Tynes 22 yd . Field Goal ( 4 - - 3 , 1 : 20 ) 0 3 Cowboys 2 1 : 01 K.Ogletree 10 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 7 - 73 , 2 : 33 ) 7 3 Cowboys 3 10 : 24 K.Ogletree 40 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 9 - 80 , 4 : 36 ) 14 3 Giants 3 5 : 11 A.Bradshaw 10 yd . run ( L.Tynes kick ) ( 9 - 89 , 5 : 13 ) 14 10 Cowboys 3 0 : 40 D.Bailey 33 yd . Field Goal ( 8 - 65 , 4 : 31 ) 17 10 Cowboys 4 5 : 57 M.Austin 34 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 8 - 82 , 7 : 06 ) 24 10 Giants 4 2 : 36 M.Bennett 9 yd . pass from E.Manning ( L.Tynes kick ) ( 12 - 79 , 3 : 21 ) 24 17 Time : 2 : 53`

The prefix to the subtrings will either be "Cowboys" or "Giants".  The string always ends with a right parenthesis `)` and two numbers.

I can't even imagine what Regex to use.  I can use string functions and loop over the string, but a Regex would help me later on.  Maybe I could use the split function, but that's over my head.

I suppose I could parse "Cowboys" then "Giants".

Comment: Can you show us an example of what result you are looking for?

Comment: Giants 2 9 : 10 L.Tynes 22 yd . Field Goal ( 4 - - 3 , 1 : 20 ) 0 3 
Cowboys 2 1 : 01 K.Ogletree 10 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick )     ( 7 - 73 , 2 : 33 ) 7 3 
Cowboys 3 10 : 24 K.Ogletree 40 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 9 - 80 , 4 : 36 ) 14 3
Giants 3 5 : 11 A.Bradshaw 10 yd . run ( L.Tynes kick ) ( 9 - 89 , 5 : 13 ) 14 10

Comment: Well, the formatting didn't work, but each substring starts with either Cowboys or Giants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this RegEx gives what you want:

```
(Cowboys|Giants).*?\)\s\d+\s\d+
```

"Cowboys" or "Giants" followed by arbitrary characters until you get a right paren, a space, some digits, a space, and some more digits.

Comment: <cfset pattern = '(Cowboys|Giants).*?\)\s\d+\s\d+' />
<cfset results = reFindAll(pattern, ScoringPlays1, 2) />
I get "Giants"

Using split;
<cfset matches = ScoringPlays1.split('(Cowboys|Giants).*?\)\s\d+\s\d+') />
I get;

Comment: 1  [empty string]
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8  Time : 2 : 53

Comment: I haven't used reFindAll but this is a pretty standard regex (I mean nothing funky like negative look-behinds).  Are you saying it doesn't accept this?  (I can't understand your comments.)

Comment: However, if I just use ;
<cfset matches = ScoringPlays1.split('(Cowboys|Giants)') />

I get the desired list.

Comment: Yes, that works (and is simpler) if your input string will never have anything else in between the segments you want to select.

Comment: @user990016 - re: *tutorial on how to use this forum*. I do not know of a "tutorial" per se, but check the [meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Chances are any questions you run into were already asked and answered there :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ColdFusion, but this does the job in python:

```
match = re.findall(re.compile('((Giants|Cowboys)(.(?!Cowboys|Giants))*.)', re.DOTALL), s)
```

where `s` is the provided string. `re.DOTALL` implies that `.` matches whitespace. `re.findall` means to do a global search, which `reFindAll` probably does as well.

The regex does this:

- Create a spanning group
- Look for "Giants" or "Cowboys" as the starting string
- Look for any character (`.`) that's not followed by the string "Cowboys" or "Giants" and matches as many as possible (which means, match all characters until the one succeeded by "Cowboys" or "Giants".
- Match another character.

Since there's three groups, the group you're interested in might be numbered differently in ColdFusion. In python, they're embedded in the parent group.

```
>>> match[0]
('Giants 2 9 : 10 L.Tynes 22 yd . Field Goal ( 4 - - 3 , 1 : 20 ) 0 3', 'Giants', '3')
>>> match[1]
('Cowboys 2 1 : 01 K.Ogletree 10 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 7 - 73 , 2 : 33 ) 7 3', 'Cowboys', '3')
>>> match[2]
('Cowboys 3 10 : 24 K.Ogletree 40 yd . pass from T.Romo ( D.Bailey kick ) ( 9 - 80 , 4 : 36 ) 14 3', 'Cowboys', '3')
```

I think in most other languages you would address `match[1], match[4], match[7], ...` instead.